# Django Model Field Metadata

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django model and I wish to denote that some of the model fields are private so that when I display a ModelForm based on this model I can display these fields marked as such.

I'd like this to be specified on the model rather than the form as I think that's where it belongs.

I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.  Can I write a decorator @private to do this?  Can anyone point me at an example?

Thanks

Comment: I would argue that as it is related to how a form is displayed it therefore belongs in the form - and it's very easy to do this in the form in Django using the 'exclude' Meta class attribute.

If you want to do it in the model you will likely need to subclass ModelForm to change the way in which it creates a form from a Model to account for your new decorator.

Comment: Just to expand on Ian's answer. You can either use `exclude` or `fields` to control what you want to display for your modelform. The use case for a decorator in a django/view context is normally for something you want to check before letting the user access the view  such as if he is logged in or not or if he has certain permissions.

Comment: Hi.  I'm already aware of and using `exclude` and `fields` to display a subset of fields, and that's all fine, but within those fields I need to tell the user that some will be publicly displayed and some won't.  I disagree that this belongs on the form, as I could also be using this to decide programatically which fields I should be displaying to other users, say, who aren't friends with said user.

Answer (score 2):

There's no one feature that perfectly fits your problem, but here's a couple of suggestions:

- Add the information to the model's Meta class, which you can then access from your form via the _meta attribute on the model
- Utilise the help_text option on your model fields (obviously this won't help you to "decide programatically which fields I should be displaying to other users")

I do agree that it's debatable as to whether this belongs at the model layer; it seems like business logic to me.